# Get MeasureGroup Dimmension Relationship type

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, olap

using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient I can get all measureGroups from given cube.

Then for each MeasureGroup I can get all associated with it MeasureGroupDimensions by MeasureGroup.Dimmensions.

Thats perfect and the question is can I get the relationship type between given measure group and dimension ? Is it regular or referenced ?

Thank You very much for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.measuregroupdimension.aspx, `MeasureGroupDimension` is an abstract class, which has different descendants `ManyToManyMeasureGroupDimension` and `RegularMeasureGroupDimension`. The latter is again subclassed to `DegenerateMeasureGroupDimension` and `ReferenceMeasureGroupDimension`.

So you should be able to get the type of the reference in C# using an if then else construct using `is` or `as` on this object with the classes you are interested in.